# Get number of latest version of an artifact from Nexus 2

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, nexus

I need to ask Nexus 2.x the question:

"What is the latest version of the artifact with the following groupId and artifactId?"

The information is needed in a Windows batch file.

I scanned the usual Maven plugins if there is something like `mvn versions:latest-version` which is usable outside a Maven project but did not find anything.

My best bet would be to write a Java program that questions the rest interface of Nexus for available artifacts and extracts the desired information from the XML. This would be suboptimal because I need to write, maintain and use another program outside the batch file. Furthermore, an `mvn` command would be repository independent (Nexus 2.x will not be around forever).

Any ideas?

Comment: Don’t go there unless you have a _very_ good reason

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Don't go _where_?

Comment: If you request the maven-metadata.xml file through a group repository Nexus will rewrite the file and set "latest" to be the highest semantic version. This will usually give you what you're looking for. But note that the highest semantic version might not be the last deployed. Also note that you can't count on "latest" as set by Maven:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464638-Why-are-the-latest-and-release-tags-in-maven-metadata-xml-not-being-updated-after-deploying-artifacts-